# Does SetTimer (with callback function) work by starting a new thread?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, timer

When using [`SetTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) this way:

```
SetTimer(hWnd, IDT_TIMER_LONGPROCESSING, 2000, (TIMERPROC) NULL);
DoSomethingElse();
```

the execution continues immediately (i.e. it's **non-blocking** and `DoSomethingElse()` is executed immediately), but when this message arrives

```
case WM_TIMER:
    if (wParam == IDT_TIMER_LONGPROCESSING)
         DoAOneSecondLongJob();
```

then it blocks the "window message loop" again during the 1-second long processing, resulting in a unresponsive interface. That's normal behaviour with `SetTimer` just posting a timer message.

But I see `SetTimer` can also be used **in a second way**, with a callback function:

```
VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime)
{ 
    DoAOneSecondLongJob();
}

// in another function    
SetTimer(hwnd, IDT_TIMER_LONGPROCESSING, 2000, (TIMERPROC) MyTimerProc);
```

Question:

- **Will this method be blocking as well?**

or

- **Will it solve the unresponsive-interface-during-1-second problem?** If so, how? Is there a new thread creation involved under the hood?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it does not use a separate thread, so yes, it will be blocking.  It is just a convenience function which is making use of `WM_TIMER` internally.  You should take a hint from the fact that it still involves a `hwnd` in its workings.

If you want something to run on a different thread, you need to start a different thread.

MSDN says:

> When you specify a **TimerProc** callback function, the default window procedure calls the callback function when it processes **WM_TIMER**. Therefore, you need to dispatch messages in the calling thread, even when you use **TimerProc** instead of processing **WM_TIMER**.

See [MSDN - SetTimer function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: `SetTimer()` is a message based timer. If you want a thread-based timer, use [`timeSetEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757634.aspx) or [`CreateTimerQueueTimer()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682485.aspx) instead.